# How to run Timer Application from Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on new function that connect to web but after a few unsuccessful attempts this request to web gets locked and I need to wait 15 min. I have timer application that I run by myself set timer and start, but I want to insert this set and run application in side of my code.

Has anyone done this before? Set timer and run windows application (any) automatically?

```
private bool TryToLogin()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPostUrl);
    LoginInfo = streamReadLogin.ReadToEnd();

    string postData = null;
    postData += "__REQUESTDIGEST=" + GetValueByID(LoginInfo);

    if (outString.IndexOf("User xxx") > -1)
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("User is all ready login");
        // here I need to run my windows application
    }

    connected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below MSDN links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.100).aspx

But you must be using .NET 3.5 or above.